# Do i need a TCP proxy?

Tags: sockets, networking, proxy

I need to intercept the communication between a client computer and the server computer, this communication is done via TCP sockets and i have to store that data in a server.
A TCP proxy can be a right solution or what should i do?

Thanks and sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tcp proxy can do the job. Also you could use wireshark on the client or server computer to capture the traffic.